# Pandas Pivot table with multi index

Tags: pandas

Input Dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to pivot my df by sorting Time Column in column wise
my output df:
[image]

Pivoting df wont give Time in sorted order. Is there any alternate way to do ?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of column `Loc_Time` with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by column `Time`, because `pivot` by default sorting:

```
df1 = df.pivot('Group','Loc_Time','Value')
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=df.sort_values('Time')['Loc_Time'].unique())
print (df1)
Loc_Time  loc1_Week1  loc2_Week1  loc3_Week1  loc1_Week2  loc2_Week2  \
Group                                                                  
prod1             10          12          14          11          13   
prod2             20          22          24          21          23   

Loc_Time  loc3_Week2  
Group                 
prod1             15  
prod2             25
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.sort_values('Time')['Loc_Time'].unique())

['loc1_Week1' 'loc2_Week1' 'loc3_Week1' 'loc1_Week2' 'loc2_Week2'
 'loc3_Week2']
```

Comment: thanks, @jezrael but my desired output is lill different from yours. I need Time column to be sorted.